# MAMP4 not launching MySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp

Downloaded MAMP4 and installed over MAMP1.9.4 (I know, it's old) with Mac OSX Sierra. Apache server launches, but not MySQL. Warned that previous db was copied to a folder named mysql56 and that on starting up MySQL need to convert db. But MySQL doesn't even start up! Activity Monitor shows no other mysql process going on. MAMP error log:

```
2017-01-16 12:35:13 47394 [ERROR] InnoDB: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size 640 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2017-01-16 12:35:13 47394 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2017-01-16 12:35:13 47394 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-01-16 12:35:13 47394 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-01-16 12:35:13 47394 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-01-16 12:35:13 47394 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I tried using the same ports as I used with MAMP1.9.4 (80 & 3306), then switched to default. Webserver address was pointing to my directory where I keep my websites. Changed it back to Applications/MAMP/htdocs. Nothing is working. :( Any help would be very much appreciated.

Oh, on my old machine running Snow Leopard, it's all still working with MAMP1.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution at http://rat32.com/rat32/2016/11/29/how-to-solve-mysql-not-starting-in-mamp-problem/#comment-175889. Removed all files except folders from Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56. Then restarted. MAMP immediately connected to the MySQL server and prompted me to upgrade my databases. All is well.

I tried other suggestions. The most common was to check for any other MySQL processes that might be running and to kill them via Terminal command. Another suggestion was to rename the files ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 in /Library/Application Support/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56, but as I had not initiated MAMP PRO, that folder did not exist. I had renamed the two files in Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56, but that didn't solve the problem. Only when I actually removed those two files and a third, then MAMP was able to connect to the MySQL server.

So it seems silly to answer my own question, but just want to put it here in case others run into the same problem.

Using MAMP 4.1 with Mac OSX Sierra.